# Outlook Web addin set panel width on startup

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I was looking to set the width of the main panel / window / task pane (unsure what the correct term is for outlook web addins using Office.js) on startup to have it open to the max allowable width. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

--- Edit ---

Maybe I'm not using the correct term but the border highlighted in this screen shot is sizable using the mouse but I would like to set it as a default. You are saying there is no way to do this? Seems like something that should be able to be set from the manifest or somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to specify the width. Besides, in OWA the pane is not resizable..

As alternative, you can use a "UI-less" button (see functionFile/ExecuteFunction manifest declarations) and call displayDialogAsync API to display a dialog with custom HTML content, and you can specify the size of this dialog when you create it.

Comment: "Besides, in OWA the pane is not resizable.." - Maybe we're not talking about the same thing but what I am referring to is definitely resizable. Can you see the screen shot I've attached and let me know if your answer is the same?

Comment: We are talking about the same thing here. The task pane is re-sizable in outlook desktop but not in outlook for web. Currently you cannot set the width to be maximum that's allowable in any client. We have received this request from other partners as well and it is in our backlog backlog. However I don't have a timeline at this point. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. You are welcome to up vote the request. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Link to our user voice page: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins